# Can you add additonal metadata via data annotations to a base model property from a child model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently working on a asp.net mvc 3 project, where I'm using a custom attribute called `[ColumnHeading]` to decorate the properties I want to display in a grid. I have a base model that has a couple of properties that sometimes need to be displayed in the grid of the child class.

Example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
  public String Status { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
  [Display(Name="Property 1")]
  [ColumnHeading]
  public String Property1 { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Property 2")]
  [ColumnHeading]
  public String Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know if this has been asked before (search around for about 3 hours) and if this even possible, but can you add the `[ColumnHeading]` attribute to the base class property in the child class e.g.?

```
public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
  public ChildClass()
  {
    // Fictional method to add attribute to property
    AddAdditionalMetaData(Status, [ColumnHeading]);
  }
  ...
}
```

I know that you can make the base class property `virtual` or make a view model of the base and child class, but the project has 40+ models that inherit from the base class, and about 30 of the child classes needs to display this base class property, so view models doensn't really make it worthwhile for one property extra.

Secondly i have to override the property several times which ends in endless repetative which i dont like, but if this is the only way. I'll do it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true)]
public class ColumnHeadingAttribute
{
    ...
```

See the `Inherited` property on the `AttributeUsageAttribute`. If you have this on your custom attribute, it will be inherited to child classes. You can then create an intermediate base viewmodel between the base viewmodel and the child viewmodels.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual string Status { get; set; }
}

public abstract class IntermediateClass : BaseClass
{
    [ColumnHeading]
    public override string Status { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass : IntermediateClass
{
    public ChildClass()
    {
        // Status will inherit the ColumnHeading attribute from IntermediateClass
    }
    ...
}
```